# Browerstack: Edge 15 on Windows 10: Localhost only performs a bing search

Tags: browserstack

My app is served on localhost. I am testing it on Browserstack: see title for browser version and OS. I'm running Chrome 59 on OSX Sierra.

I've tried entering `localhost:PORT`, and `http://localhost:PORT` but am always given a Bing search result for that string, instead of directing to my development server.  I know the server is up because I'm doing manual testing on Firefox, Safari, and Chrome.

I've also attempted to change Edge settings in guides like [this one](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2993839/windows/how-to-remove-bing-from-edge-or-internet-explorer.html), but there the button to remove bing completely does not exist.

Can anyone point me at support/docs that disable this functionality? Thanks!

Comment: This is default behaviour of Edge, if HTTP is not entered in the address bar results redirect to bing.com. You should be able to test if you are entering HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mukesh. The question above has `http://localhost:PORT` as something I tried.  Am I missing something?